# How do I load values into a class

Tags: c#-4.0

Here is what I want to be happened.
  I am working on a Win Forms application.
  I want a class to run first then store values in a different class which has a struct in it which holds a value.
  Now when the Form `frmMainConsole` loads I want it to read the values from the struct to set certain properties on the form.

Here is what I have tried:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMainConsole());
    }
```

here is the class with the struct:

```
public class MyAppSetting
{
    //View Setting
     public bool ShowMoves { get; set; }
}
```

Now when the frmMainConsoleLoads which is here:

```
private void frmMainConsole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CreateGroupBox();
        //Set Initial Settings
        MyAppSetting MyAppSetting = new ChessStrategyGame.MyAppSetting();
        movesToolStripMenuItem.Checked = MyAppSetting.ShowMoves;

    }
```

Now the class I want to use to start the application looks like this:

```
class StartUp
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyAppSetting MyAppSetting = new MyAppSetting();
        MyAppSetting.ShowMoves = true;

        //On the Main Form of application
        Form frmMainConsole = new frmMainConsole();
        frmMainConsole.Show();
    }
}
```

Basically I want the application to remember certain settings from the last time it was run

Comment: From last time it was run??? you may need external text filefor doing it

Comment: I think what I actually want to do is load the class called startup then open the FORm frmMainConsole.

Comment: You should have edited your first question ...

Comment: @nicael Can you make your edits more substantial, please. And did the formname really needed the backticks?